# How to handle the pop-up as webpage and alert both simultaneously?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image: I am not able to fill this form and also not able to handle the alert obtain on top left corner]

Please help me to fill this form and then going on to the website along with handling the alert.

Here is my code which is not working:

```
public class FirstCry {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\CP-SAT\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver a = new ChromeDriver();
            a.get("http://www.firstcry.com/");
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
            a.manage().window().maximize();

            String k = a.getPageSource();
            System.out.println(k);

            WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(a, 30);
            Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='amt']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div")));

            WebElement b = a.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='amt']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div"));
            b.click();

        }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use window handles.

Comment: All opening in single window. So no use of Windows handlers

Comment: @KishanPatel try with updated answer, It will handle your popup and notification alert both..thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [website](http://www.firstcry.com/) popup present inside an `iframe` with id `iframe_Login`, you need to switch that `iframe` before finding the close button of the popup as below :-

```
//Create this prefs to handle notification popup
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

//Initialize chrome option to add prefs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

//Now initialize chrome driver with chrome option to handle notification alert
WebDriver a = new ChromeDriver(options)

a.get("http://www.firstcry.com/");
a.manage().window().maximize();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(a, 30)

//Now find iframe and switch to it
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("iframe_Login"));

//Now find the popup close button
WebElement b = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class = '_pop_close _pop_reg_bg']")));
b.click();

//Now switch back from frame to default content for further steps
a.switchTo().defaultContent();

//Now do your further stuff
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Excellent.. And what about the pop-up. I used alert.dismiss(); , but it is not working. Can you help me for pop-up which is there on top left corner ..?

Comment: Can I close through some settings in browser, so that when i run my script it won't come again?

Comment: @KishanPatel Got it...No need some extra setting.. just using chrome pref you can handle it.. try with updated answer..:)